# QToolBar Change Height

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets, qtoolbar

In my project I have a `QToolBar` with default size and size policy. I want to increase the height of the toolbar to 36px.

So far I have tried:

- Setting a stylesheet property to the toolbar: `height: 36px;`
- Setting the toolbar object's size policy to fixed: `toolBar->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Fixed);`
- Setting the minimumHeight: `toolBar->setMinimumHeight(36);`
- Setting the layout size constraint `toolBar->layout()->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetMinimumSize)`
- All of those at once

And nothing increases the height of the toolbar. The only thing that works is increasing the size of the `QToolButton` objects within the bar, but this is not what I want to do. I only want the toolbar itself taller.

Any suggestions? Thanks for your time.

EDIT: My current solution was to add a margin to the QToolButton objects in the toolbar. I still don't like this because I have varying object types in the toolbar.... frustrating.

Comment: In my projects using setFixedHeight on QToolBar works fine

Comment: @Andre Huh when I tried it it still didn't work. Did you need to do anything else? Like set a specific size policy or something?

Comment: No, I just set the height of the toolbar with the function I told you, nothing else: no size policy, no size constraint, no minimum height. Could be stupid but have you tried to call show() function on your QToolBar when you have set it up?

Comment: @Andre Okay THAT'S weird. I just tried it again and it's working now O_o. I'm trying to replicate the issue now and I can't. huh.... well thanks for your help! :) setFixedHeight is the answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`toolBar->setFixedHeight(36);` - works well.

But if I set icon size after this:

```
toolBar->setFixedHeight(36); 
toolBar->setIconSize(QSize(10, 10));
```

height breaks down. Also it happens if I set icon size via stylesheet.

Changing of calls order helps:

```
toolBar->setIconSize(QSize(10, 10));
toolBar->setFixedHeight(36);
```

Answer (score 1):

`toolbar->setFixedHeight(36)` should work

[Documentation here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setFixedHeight)

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed the same problem with a QToolBar in my project, which didn't change its height although explicitly calling `setMinimumHeight(64)` on it. Turned out that delaying this into the main thread's eventloop using a singleShot QTimer helps:

```
# self is an instance of a QToolBar subclass
QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, lambda : self.setMinimumHeight(64))
```

(It's in PyQt5, but you should get the point.)